# How to check the selected radiobutton?

Tags: android, view, radio-button, selecteditem, android-radiogroup

I try to check the selected radio button,

I found a little detail, but I can't paste it.

Now i have one (View View ) error.

The program don't know which one was selected ,

and i can't find the solution.

What can i write more ?

Please help.

Thank you : ant Z
[picture from the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3L9G.jpg)

My code:

```
package myapplication.Buttons;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;     
    
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);
       editText = findViewById(R.id.text);
        RadioGroup radioGroup =  findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {            
            //do something  }           
            });

        public void getSelectedRadioButton(View View ) {        <<< fail here :(View View )
            final RadioGroup radGroup = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);
            int radioID = radGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton singleButton = findViewById(radioID);
        }
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1); 

                                 <<< if i push the btn1 the program don't know the radioID>>>

                if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioButton_green) {
                //do something
                }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something
        }
    } );
    }}
```

Comment: `View View` case sensetive. Must be: `View view`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work on 2 things to get this fixed.

1. Make the correction of case sensitivity and correct `View View` as `View view`
2. Move the function below the onCreate function and inside the MainActivity.
3. You don't actually need 1&2 to get what you desire.
4. You can copy-paste this code and get working.

Code:

```
package myapplication.Buttons;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.uploadedlobster.PwdHash.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.text);
        RadioGroup radioGroup =  findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioButton_green) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remained.
I put up a picture of the original problem, maybe it will help.